# How to remove specific character from column in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a attribute where  * is present along with numerical values. I wish to remove this * mark from the numerical value. What should I try?
Example- Transforming A to B
Column A - 54, 6*, 9, 0, 189*, 34, 58*
Column B-  54, 6 , 9, 0, 189 , 34, 58

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsub` with `fixed = TRUE` as `*` is a  metacharacter which means 0 or more character.  Therefore, we need either `fixed =TRUE` (or escape `\\*` or place it inside square brackets `[*]`) to get the literal value

```
gsub("*", "", df1$Column1, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "54"  "6"   "9"   "0"   "189" "34"  "58"
```

If there is only one `*` in each of the string, then `sub` is sufficient

```
sub("*", "", df1$Column1, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "54"  "6"   "9"   "0"   "189" "34"  "58"
```

Or

```
sub("\\*", "", df1$Column1)
#[1] "54"  "6"   "9"   "0"   "189" "34"  "58"
```

Or

```
sub("[*]", "", df1$Column1)
#[1] "54"  "6"   "9"   "0"   "189" "34"  "58"
```

and then do `as.numeric` to convert to `numeric`

```
as.numeric(sub("[*]", "", df1$Column1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sub("\\*","",A)
[1] "- 54" " 6"   " 9"   " 0"   " 189" " 34"  " 58"
```